# Post method not working with WebAPI 2 and Angular 4

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to learn Angular4 and implementing post method developed in ASP WebAPI and fetching into Angular4 application.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class APIController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/savePerson")]
    public IHttpActionResult savePerson(PersonModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            if (model.name != string.Empty || model.weight != 0 || model.height != 0 || model.proffession != 0)
            {
                Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
                Random random = new Random();
                int i = random.Next();
                model.id = i;
                return Ok(model);
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return InternalServerError("Something Went Wrong : " + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

I have added System.Web.Cors from nuget package. 
In my Angular class I am trying to post the values like this:
**Services.ts**

```
addPerson(person : Person){
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.post(this.Base_URL + 'savePerson', person, options)
      .map(res=><Person>res.json()).catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

When I try to test the API from Postman, its working fine. But, when I try to call it from my Angular application I am getting error like this:

> OPTIONS http://sampleapi.ubiquitousdevelopers.com/api/savePerson 405
>   (Method Not Allowed) Failed to load
>   http://sampleapi.ubiquitousdevelopers.com/api/savePerson: Response for
>   preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405

[image]

Its just a sample API so I didn't hide my Base URL. Anyone can test this API.
My Get methods are working fine on this URL:
http://sampleapi.ubiquitousdevelopers.com/api/getAllperson

POSTMAN Working Screenshot:
[image]

**My Web.Config file**

```
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

Comment: Error message indicates you are trying to use HTTP Verb OPTIONS but you only allow POST in the backend.. That will result in a 405 error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably has to do with CORS (cross origin requests).

When doing CORS and OPTIONS request will fire first.

When doing CORS, you need to change some things in your web.config.

Here is a sample from my web.config. I use this config for **development**.

```
<system.webServer>
<defaultDocument enabled="false" />
<directoryBrowse enabled="false" />

<!-- https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/fundamentals/servers -->
<!-- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/hosting/aspnet-core-module -->
<handlers>
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
  <!--<add name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" path="*" verb="OPTIONS" modules="ProtocolSupportModule" requireAccess="None" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />-->

</handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

In this snippet I first remove OPTIONS and TRACE handlers and afterwards open all http verbs to all paths with the line:

Notice also that I did this is a ASP.NET Core project.

For ASP.NET MVC 5:

```
  <system.webServer>
<defaultDocument enabled="false" />
<directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  <!--<add name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" path="*" verb="OPTIONS" modules="ProtocolSupportModule" requireAccess="None" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />-->
</handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Other possibility is to allow CORS headers like this:

```
<system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
<customHeaders>
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With"/>
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, OPTIONS"/>
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
```

Comment: so you have removed OptionsVerbHandler in webconfig right?

Comment: I have pasted my webconfig in question. I don't know what is wrong in that?

Comment: No, I did not just remove it.
<add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>

This line opens all methods, in ASP.NET Core.

Answer (score 1):

In order to enable CORS, you also need to call [`EnableCors`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.corshttpconfigurationextensions.enablecors(v=vs.118).aspx) on your `HttpConfiguration`. See [here](https://enable-cors.org/server_aspnet.html) or [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#enable-cors):

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // New code
        config.EnableCors();

        ...
```

Just using the `EnableCors` attribute on its own is not enough.

Comment: I think I have enable Cors on controller by [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]

Comment: Yes, you have that but you also need what I said in the answer - you need both.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting 405(Method not allow) which is obviously CORS issue, So I need to enable CORS.

First of all I need to enable CORS in WebAPIConfig.cs by

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // New code
        config.EnableCors();

        ...
```

Also, just enabling CORS in WebAPIConfig.cs is not enough. I was getting same error if I run the code. So I need to decorate my Controller by :

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class APIController : ApiController
{
```

Now When I run the code I get following error:

> The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*,
>   *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.

By Searching on stackoverflow I come to know that my EnableCors header conflicts with my Web.Config CORS header.

So I removed custom header from Web.Config

```
 <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, OPTIONS"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

Also, VRPF, I did not make any changes in default handler and keep it as it is:

```
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

Now I test, all working fine. I think this could be helpful to any new Angular Developer while learning purpose.

Finally its solved by help of Kirk Larkin and VRPF after 3 weeks of searching. Cheers :D